# How to refactor function from global namespace into function in defined namespace in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm

Is there a automated way in PhpStorm of moving a PHP function from global namespace (there is none defined) into a defined namespace? I'm not talking about a class method here, also the function [should stay a function](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2015/08/namespace-php-functions/) and not become a class method.

```
<?php

function a() {}

$a = a();

// should become this:

namespace A\B;
function a() {};

// somewhere else ... 
use function A\B\a;
$a = a();
```

Comment: This isn't available in PhpStorm yet. You can vote for a corresponding feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-44703

Comment: @Dmitrii thank you for the information and clarifiaction!